# Create Policy to whitelist IP but just for specific URL on Amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have two Amazon EC2 instances.

One of them running a node.js server and the other one running a rails server.
I want to create a policy that does the following:
 - node.js server (say IP XXX.XXX.XXX.X) should be able to access the other Amazon EC2 instance, but just a specific URL.

For example, my rails server has the following routes:

```
/login
/index
/dummy
```

I want /index and /dummy to be available from anywhere. But I want /login to be available just from node server (IP  XXX.XXX.XXX.X)

Is this doable?
Thanks!

Comment: The only place you can reliably do this is within your application.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way to configure amazon policies to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS firewalls allow you to restrict access to specific ports for specific IP ranges.

This level of fine-grained access is not something AWS will handle for you. It belongs in the application itself.